# Can exponential object be defined in terms of universal construction?

Tags: category-theory

From *Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists*

> Let $C$ be a category with all binary products and let $A$ 
>   and $B$ be objects of $C$. An object $B^A$ is an exponential object if there is 
>   an arrow $eval_{AB}  : (B^A  \times A)  \to  B$ such that for any object $C$ and arrow 
>   $g: (C \times A)\to B$ there is a unique arrow $curry(g): C \to B^A$ such that 
>   $eval_{AB} \circ (curry(g)  \times id_A) =g$.
>
> [image]

Can exponential object be defined in terms of [universal construction](https://books.google.com/books?id=ezdeaHfpYPwC&lpg=PA20&ots=_m5_6Cxrj4&dq=A%20universal%20construction%20describes%20a%20class%20of%20objects%20and%20accompanying%20arrows%20that%20share%20a%20common%20property%20and%20picks%20out%20the%20objects%20that%20are%20terminal&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=A%20universal%20construction%20describes%20a%20class%20of%20objects%20and%20accompanying%20arrows%20that%20share%20a%20common%20property%20and%20picks%20out%20the%20objects%20that%20are%20terminal&f=false)?

> **A universal construction** describes a class of objects and accompanying arrows that share a common property and picks out **the objects 
>   that are terminal** when this class is considered as a category.

Comment: What do you mean ? This is a definition by a universal property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: take the category in which an object is a pair $(X,f)$ where $X$ is an object of $C$ and $f:X\times A\to B$, and a morphism between two such objects $(X,f)$ and $(Y,g)$ is an arrow $h:X\to Y$ such that $g\circ (h\times id_A)=f$.  Your given definition then says exactly that an exponential object $(B^A,eval_{AB})$ is a terminal object in this category.